# Activity history is invisible to new owner

Tags: activities

I changed one account owner and now new owner not able to view activity history created by old owner. The Sharing setting for activity is controlled by parent. For account its Read/Write. What will be the possible case here? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a same page layout assigned to new user profile?. if not pls verify page layout and activity history related list.

Comment: Page layout is same for both profiles but still new owner not able to see activity history records.

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing Model**

When the activity sharing model is “Controlled By Parent,” people with “View All” permission for the type of object on the related record can view the activity.

There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gS3UAAU) for Activity History Visibility

Check [Access Activities in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. but i want to know that which activity history a user can view? Is it depend on due date?

Comment: In a Private Sharing model with Activities controlled by parent, users can only view activities on the Activity related list if the activity is assigned to that user.

Comment: Thank you Devendra. But i cant understand that why new owner can not see activity history if he is already owner of record now. Is there any other solution for this insted of View All?